# Angular - Show Bootstrap Modal on Form Submit condition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a Angular 5 form based on the Model Driven Approach. I have validated and stuff and make the API call. Once the api call returns a value, I set an indicator `true` or `false`. Based upon this returned value, I want to show a standard modal indicating the result and also clear the form contents if it was successful. Below is my code:

`signup.component.html`:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="register(myForm.value)" id="signUpForm" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter Email..." class="form-control" aria-required="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
....
<div class="modal fade" [hidden]="!myForm.valid">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">User Register</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Signup done!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my `signup.component.ts`:

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean = false;

  constructor(...
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")]]
    });
  }

  register(model: User) {
    this.authService.register(model.email)
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.submitted = true;
      },
      error => {
        this.submitted = false;
      });
  }

}
```

So the problems again:
1 - The modal doesn't popup even if the value is true.
2 - Once the value does become true, I want the form to be reset.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: 1 - The modal doesn't popup even if the value is true. 2 - Once the value does become true, I want the form to be reset.

Comment: @JBNizet any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For opening bootrap modal from component you need to declare

```ts
declare var $;
```

outside component. Then when you want to display the modal after successfully submitting, use `ViewChild` and

```ts
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// ...

@ViewChild('someModal') someModal:ElementRef;

register(model: any) {
  this.submitted = true;
  // ...
  $(this.someModal.nativeElement).modal('show'); 
}
```

As for removing the values from form, you can just call `this.myForm.reset()`

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aheyn7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

You could also consider using **[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)** :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers above did not work for me on Angular 9.1.12

I do have a lot of other dependencies and stuff in my project so it could be some issues that I'm not seeing.  This worked for me though:

1. Add `private modalService: NgbModal` to your constructor
2. Add your form variable like `<ng-template #askApprovalModal >`
3. Add your element accessor like `@ViewChild('askApprovalModal') askApprovalElementRef:ElementRef;` to your .ts class
4. Add a button to trigger the condition to open the modal
   `<button (click)="f() > </button>"`
5. Using NgbModal this is where the magic happens, add this function to your .ts class

   ```
   open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
   }
   ```
6. Add the handle to your click event

   ```
   f(){
    this.open(this.askApprovalElementRef)
   }
   ```

Your modal css will be up to you to conclude.